# 415 Unsupported Media Type. Content-Type set

Tags: json, rest, post, jersey

I've set the content type of my request and am still getting an unsupported media type exception.  Looking for a second set of eyes here....

My java code:

```
@Path("/myPath")
public class MyResource {

    SensorStore dataStore = new SensorStoreDynamoImpl();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Reading getObj(String id) {
        return dataStore.getValue(id);
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void saveObj(String id, Double myDouble, Long myLong) {
        dataStore.saveReading(id, myDouble, myLong);
    }

}
```

Call I'm making:

```
POST to /myPath

Header:
Content-Type: application/json

Body:

{
id:"test", 
myDouble:22.2, 
myLong:22
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: i had same problem i changed media type to Text_Plain then it is working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That doesn't look like any valid resource method I'm aware of. I'd love to be corrected if there's some advanced feature I don't know about, but I've never known JAX-RS/Jersey to let you bind arbitrary JSON fields to method parameters by name. You'd need something more like:

```
class MyPojo {
    String id;
    Double myDouble;
    Long myLong;
}

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void saveObj(MyPojo myPojo) {
    dataStore.saveReading(myPojo.id, myPojo.myDouble, myPojo.myLong);
}
```

Comment: I confirm you can not do such thing. Jersey (nor other jax-rs impl) can bind json content to multiple parameters. You can only bind the full json to a single param. Also the names from the json must be quoted

Comment: One more thing I was missing.  @XmlRootElement on the POJO

Comment: True, if you're using JAXB for JSON, you'll need that. If you set [FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#json), you'll get more flexibility in your JSON, and it uses Jackson, which doesn't require any annotation to convert objects.